# MySQL select one record from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables, records

I have 400+ tables and each has a column timestamp. I'd like to pull the first row/record for timestamp for each of these tables. I don't want to run 400+ queries, what would the best way to do this be?

Comment: This kind of problem is sometimes symptomatic of (appallingly) poor design.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a **UNION** query like this:

```sql
SELECT Id, yourColumn, timestamp FROM Table001 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, yourColumn, timestamp FROM Table002 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Id, yourColumn, timestamp FROM Table003 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Use a loop to create this statement:

```
SET @resultQuery = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT
    CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name, ' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 ')
    SEPARATOR '\r\nUNION\r\n'
  )
INTO
  @resultQuery
FROM
  information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
  table_schema = '???' AND column_name LIKE '%timestamp';

SELECT @resultQuery;
```

Comment: I don't want to select a specific timestamp but rather the first record of each table and the corresponding value from column timestamp

Comment: ORDER BY timestamp DESC or ASC (for each table) and than LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

The need for the first record from 400+ tables smells like poor design, but if they have the same schema, you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM bar ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM baz ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1
-- etc...
```

Comment: This is a one time use that the DB was not designed for so I'm not sure if it's poor design or not but I wouldn't be surprised. So I'll have to create a query 800+ lines long?